# Navigation Bar not show in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: swift3, uinavigationbar, xcode8, navigationbar, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I used **JSQMessages** for my app.
[image]


 When I add ***navigation bar*** in the view controller, it does not show however I make constraints for the bar. 
Please help me.

Comment: Could you include the code that you use to present this. That would help us understand what you are doing and how to best help you. Thanks

Comment: Hello bro @DanielLeonard, now I can solve this problem by adding Navigation Controller. :D Thanks for asking me to help.

Comment: Im confused. Did you figure it out ?

Comment: Firstly, I would like to add navigation bar in that view controller. So, I put it and make constraints. It did not appear when I run. So, I find it in google for solutions. The main reason of why it did not show is that JSQMessager. Most people also encounter that problem. Finally, I add Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller. After I embed that, navigation bar is appear now. That problem was solved.  Now, I have another problem :( I don't even know how to give question title in stack overflow. :(

Comment: Best way is to give a screen shot of what you have and what you want.

Comment: Yes bro @DanielLeonard. Here is my new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623798/tabbar-item-in-swift .  Actually, I don't know how to explain to more clear. I try my best. Please check it. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to close this question.

Comment: Yes bro. I want to do.

Comment: You can just hit the ... and delete it if you solved it yourself.